# Secure password communication between 2 applications

Tags: c#, security, process, passwords, password-encryption

I am writing a program, which is like a swiss army knife of tools that my colleagues need in their day to day work. One feature of this tool is, to be able to connect to a client remotely and control it. 
We already have an application called [Dameware Mini Remote Control](https://www.dameware.com/dameware-mini-remote-control), not written by us, that does this exact job. My application just starts this software in a process and hands over username and password, the user has entered beforehand.

In the documentation of the Dameware Tool, it says that the process should be called with these arguments:
"dwrcc.exe [-?|-?:] [-c:] [-h:] [-m:MachineName] [-u:UserName] [-p:Password | -p:"Password"] [-d:Domain] [-o:TCPport] [-s:SharedSecret] [-r:] [-vnc:] [-a:0|1|2] [-prxa:MRCproxyAddress] [-prxp:MRCproxyPort] [-prxsMRCproxySecret] [-v:] [-md:] [-i:n] [-x:] [-bh:CentralServerHostAddress] [-bpn: CentralServerPortNumber] [-bu:CentralServerUserName] [-bps:CentralServerUserPassword]"

My concern is that providing the password in the -p option is not secure, because it is basically plain text.

Here is the part of my code where i provide the command line arguments:

```cs
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-c: -h: -x: -m:{TxtHostname} -d:{MainUI.Credentials.DomainName} -u:{MainUI.Credentials.UserName} -p:{LoginCredentials.Decrypt(MainUI.Credentials.EncryptedPassword)}";
```

Is there a secure way of handing over the password to the Dameware application inside the process?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can secure the communication the client and server by using TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in general. If the only option is to pass the password via a command line parameter, you do only have this option.

However it would be possible if the target application supports another way of receiving the password. This is application specific and doesn't apply to every application.

As I'm not familiar with Dameware Mini Remote Control, I can't tell if such an option exists in this specific case.